# How to get smooth animation while scrolling in ios

Tags: javascript, ios

Smooth scrolling doesn't work in ios.

I have a `window.scroll` function with `behavior: 'smooth'` property.
this works fine in android. but in ios there is no animation.
(the scroll did happen)

```
window.scroll({
      top: 100,
      behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving over flow scroll to touch

```
.scroll-touch {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```